# Simple Injector the type is directly or indirectly depending on itself

Tags: c#, configuration, global-asax, simple-injector

I am getting a Simple Injector error within my Global.asax.

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type
>   IQueryHandler<GetShipmentByIdAndCompanyQuery, ShipmentQueryResult>
>   failed. The configuration is invalid. The type ShipmentPlanningHelper
>   is directly or indirectly depending on itself. The cyclic graph
>   contains the following types: ShipmentPlanningHelper ->
>   ShipmentPlanningHelper -> MissingCmrShipmentsHelper ->
>   MissingCmrShipmentsHelper -> ShipmentPlanningHelper.

What can be the reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: "What can be the reason for this?". Well, the exception states that "ShipmentPlanningHelper is directly or indirectly depending on itself" and that your graph is "cyclic ". It even shows you how the graph is cyclic by presenting you with the types in the chain: "ShipmentPlanningHelper -> ShipmentPlanningHelper -> MissingCmrShipmentsHelper -> MissingCmrShipmentsHelper -> ShipmentPlanningHelper". So what is your question exactly?

Comment: Well i'm new to this and don't know how to fix this. Is this something I have to fix in my global.asax? Or did I do something else wrong?

Comment: You will have to change the design of your system, because this object graph can't be created. Not by Simple Injector, nor any other DI Container, nor by hand using plain old C# code. How to change the design, however, is not something we can answer, because 1. this is primary opinion-based, and 2. you didn't show any details of what those classes do. My experience, however, is that most cyclic graphs are caused by [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) violations. Tip: try making your classes smaller.

Comment: Pro tip: read [this section](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-6/232) from [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://manning.com/seemann2) about cyclic dependencies.

Comment: I fixed it after reading some of your links. Thanks!